# ¿Cómo añadir un placeholder a un div?

Tags: html

Tengo un `div` que hace de `textarea` y necesito un `placeholder`... Esto no me funciona:

```
<div placeholder="El texto va aquí"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué usar un `div` como `textarea` si existen los `textarea`s para dicho propósito? ;)

Comment: @kerunaru tiene otra pregunta al respecto. mira su perfil heheh

Comment: @kerunaru para guardar los `<br>` y `<b></b>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encontré [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20300212/3045491) de SOeng pero que no se "ve" muy bien el `div` y le añadí un `border`:

En el `css` pone `content:attr(placeholder)` pero si tu atributo lo quieres llamar `textoDentro="Texto aqui"` en el `css` has de poner `content:attr(textoDentro)`

```css
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(placeholder)
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable=true placeholder="Tu texto aqui"></div>
```

Comment: Esto lo tengo que añadir al `<style> </style>` o donde?

Comment: @lukas Si, es CSS ^^ (si editas  mi respuesta puedes entrar en el snippet y ver cada apartado HTML, CSS, JS)

Comment: Me funciona tu ejemplo, pero no en mi codigo, pero doy respuesta por valida porque eso funciona. Gracias !

Comment: Oh, pero tenemos que solucionarlo. por que no te funciona? sale algo? algun mensaje de error?

Comment: He encontrado la solución: Yo tenía un espacio entre los DIVs de este modo `<div ...> </div>`, solucion: borrar espacio `<div ...></div>` :) gracias !

Comment: Ah, *fiuuu* me alegro. :D